adding strings of billions to javascript/angular array of numbers acting strange
I've got an array of objects with a targeted field containing a string value that could be greater or less than a billion. When I loop through and push the strings to my array: number[], values over a billion magically become values like 5. Hundreds of millions work fine. I've tried a several strategies (BigInt, if/else to sort on value, etc.), but I'm missing something dumb here. Here is the code block:
    (response) => {
      response.forEach(element => {

        this.valueArray.push(parseInt(element.value))

each element is an object from an api like { hamburgers: '7', hotdogs: '9', feelings: 'strong' value: '9000000000'}
The valueArray is being used to populate a chart.js barchart, and if there are values being converted from 1,000,000,001 to 1, the chart looks crazy.
Thanks in advance!
I thought this might work but it doesn't behave like I thought it would and return NaN:
`    if(element.value.length < 10) {
                      this.value.push(Number(element.value))
                      return;
                    }
                    else if(element.value.length > 9) {
                      this.value.push(Number(BigInt(element.value)))
                    }
                    break;`


I can't reproduce. The values you are talking about are orders of magnitude less than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and parse fine for me...

Various JavaScript operators implicitly convert numbers to 32-bit integers, and 9 billion doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer.

Here is one solution that did not work, it returns NaN: this.getUsdaSubscription = this.newUsdaData$
.subscribe({
next: (response) => {
response.forEach(element => {
          switch(selectedMetric) {
            case 'AREA PLANTED':
                this.period.push(element.year + ' ' + element.reference_period_desc)
                debugger
                this.tempDecimal = +(element.value) * 1
                console.log(this.tempDecimal)
                this.value.push(this.tempDecimal)

